# Question about infinite intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is  $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty (0, 1 + \frac{1}{n})$ equal to $(0, 1)$ or $(0,1]$?  Help is appreciated.

Comment: $1\in (0,1+\frac 1 n)$ for all $n$ what does that tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $n$, $1\in\left(0,1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(0,1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\left\{x,\,\forall n,\,x\in\left(0,1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right\}$. 
So $1\in\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(0,1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

*More generally :*
The same way, we can show that $\displaystyle(0,1]\subset\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(0,1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$.
If $x>1$, it exists $n$ such as $x\notin\left(0,1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$, so $\displaystyle x\notin\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(0,1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$.
If $x\le 0$, $x\notin(0,\frac{1}{1})$, so $\displaystyle x\notin\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(0,1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$.
Conclusion : $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(0,1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=(0,1]$.

Answer (score 11):

Well... is $1$ included in all sets being intersected, or is it missing from at least one? If it is missing from at least one, then it is not in the intersection. If it is included in all sets being intersected, then it *is* in the intersection.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** For all $n$ we have $1\in(0,1+\frac1n)$.